# How to access files in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So in HTML I can do something this:

```
<input type="file" id="upload" accept="text" multiple/>
```

Then I can access the files uploaded in JavaScript like this whenever the input changes:

```
document.getElementById('upload').onchange = function(){
  const uFiles = this.files;
  console.log(uFiles);
}
```

How would I go about doing that with ReactJS? So far, I've tried using the same approach I would use for HTML and JavaScript but I get the response that uFiles is undefined rather than a FileList object.

---

In my React Render:

```
<input onChange={this.doFunc} id="upload" type="file" accept="text" multiple />
```

In my React class:

```
doFunc = () => {

  const uFiles = this.files;
  console.log(uFiles);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to use  event.

```
   doFunc = e => {

      const uFiles = e.target.files;
      console.log(uFiles);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function handleUploadChange(e)
{
    const file = e.target.files[0];
    if ( !file )
    {
        return;
    }
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsBinaryString(file);

    reader.onload = () => {
        console.log(reader.result);
        console.log(file.type);
    };

    reader.onerror = function () {
        console.log("error on load image");
    };
}
```

Comment: May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post. See also [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers).